# Mail on an error

Tags: mail, pipe

I would like to be notified by email whenever my web-application does an error.

In [this link](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/90), someone says that "Guys, just pipe ~/.pm2/logs/*.err to your favourite mailer, all data are there.".

I didn't understand what exactly I should do - what does it mean to "pipe the files to the mailer"? What should I do in order to get an email when there is a new line in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

General about  [Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)

You can use [mutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_%28e-mail_client%29) as mailer or write your own.

Example:

```
cat ~/.pm2/logs/*.err|mutt -s "Critical error" me@myhost.net
```